# Saving Radio buttons info on php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently working on a voting project, i have a form that is populated from the database and i managed to use loops to generate radio buttons. However the radio button can only select one answer out of the possible eight, i need it to select an answer in each and every question. i know the radio button names are the same and the need to be different, however its a loop so i dont know how to change the names. any help?

Here is the code

```
<?php $title="POLLS | Voting - Home";
require_once( "includes/session.php");
include( "includes/connection.php"); 
include( "includes/header.php"); 
$query="SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_id={$_SESSION['user_id']}" ;
$result=mysql_query($query,$connection); 
$row=mysql_fetch_row($result);
$_SESSION[ 'user_id']=$row[0]; ?>

<body>
    <div id="outerDiv">
        <div id="header">
            <div id="mainMenu"> </div>
            <!-- mainMenu -->
        </div>
        <!-- header -->
        <div id="midBanner"> </div>
        <div id="content">
            <div id="mainContent">
                <p>Welcome,
                    <?php echo strtoupper($_SESSION[ 'username'])?>!</p>
                <form action="votingpage.php" method="post">
                    <?php $query="SELECT question_id,question FROM questions " ; $result=mysql_query($query, $connection); ?>
                    <form>
                        <table class="Question Table">
                            <th></th>
                            <?php echo "<tr>"; echo "<tr>"; echo "<tr>"; ***strong text***$num_rows="" ; $counter=$num_rows; while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){ echo "<br />"; $counter +=1 ; echo "<br />"; echo $counter; echo $row[ 'question']; echo "<br />"; $query1="SELECT qstn_ans_id, possible_answer FROM qanswers WHERE question_id= " . $row[ 'question_id'] ; $result1=mysql_query($query1, $connection); while($row1=mysql_fetch_assoc($result1)){ echo "<input type='radio' name='possible_answer'".$row1[ 'qstn_ans_id']. " value='".$row1[ 'qstn_ans_id']. "'/> ".$row1[ 'possible_answer']; echo "<br />"; } } ?> </table>
                    </form>
            </div>
            <!-- mainContent -->
            <p class="clear" /> </div>
        <!-- content -->
    </div>
    <!-- outerDiv -->
    <?php include( "includes/footer.php"); ?>
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please use code blocks for your code snippet.

Comment: And formatting within code block would be nice. One line is nigh unreadable.